# How can I include Wordpress sidebar in a query array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating wordpress loop to show only posts by specified ID's. I'd like admin to be bale to choose the ID's manually, so I created custom text widget where they can input posts ID's that they want to display. Now I'd like to pass that widget value into WP-Query, but instead of showing posts it only displays the three ID's as numbers. I tried the loop code with typed in ID's and it worked fine, why it doesn't work when I'm including the sidebar with widget? Could anyone help me how to sort this out?

That's the beginning of my query:

```
<?php 
$from_widget = dynamic_sidebar( 'my-widget' );
$include_ids = array( $from_widget );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $include_ids ) );
?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
....
```

Comment: This doesn't work because you're putting what I assume are comma-delimited numbers into an array as one string. E.g. `array( [0] => '1,2,3' )` instead of `array( [0] => 1, [1] => 2 )`. Use `explode()`. Even though that should work I'd strongly advise picking a different method. It's not an appropriate use of a widget.

Comment: I know it's not the best solution to use widget for that, but I am not allowed to use plugins, I was thinking about custom fields but they are per post, not global. Is there any other simple way to add textfield in admin area?

Comment: @NathanDawson thanks, I tried with explode(), and when using like this `explode( $from_widget );` it works and lists the posts, but I get error that second parameter is missing, so I tried `explode(",", $from_widget );` but then again the output is only: 1,2,3 as text